# Can auto generated queries from annotations be query cached with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, memcached

```
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "campaignChallenge" )
@OrderBy( "challengeGameNumber ASC" )
public List<ChallengeGame> getChallengeGames() {
    return challengeGames;
}
```

In the example above I'm using JPA to annotate.  It will auto create a query when I call the method getChallengeGames.

select challengeg0_.campaign_challenge_id as campaign6_2_, challengeg0_.challenge_game_id as challenge1_2_, challengeg0_.challenge_game_id as challenge1_5_1_, challengeg0_.campaign_challenge_id as campaign6_5_1_, challengeg0_.challenge_game_number as challenge2_5_1_, challengeg0_.field_art_logo_url as field3_5_1_, challengeg0_.game_mode_id as game7_5_1_, challengeg0_.goal as goal5_1_, challengeg0_.team_group_id as team8_5_1_, challengeg0_.user_team_origin as user5_5_1_, teamgroup1_.team_group_id as team1_63_0_, teamgroup1_.affiliation as affiliat2_63_0_, teamgroup1_.hidden as hidden63_0_, teamgroup1_.name as name63_0_, teamgroup1_.team_group_type as team5_63_0_ from challenge_game challengeg0_ left outer join team_group teamgroup1_ on challengeg0_.team_group_id=teamgroup1_.team_group_id where challengeg0_.campaign_challenge_id=? order by challengeg0_.challenge_game_number ASC

Is there anyway to get it to use the hibernate query cache?  If I create the query directly I need to use a jpa call to set the hint to cache. Is there an annotation equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you read this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-cache ?
I found there everything what i needed.